# Sensor fusion for IMU

Tags: control-theory, aerospace-engineering, sensors, robotics, embedded-systems

I'm working with MPU-6050 sensor with Raspberry Pi 4. I can read acceleration and gyroscope raw data from the sensor. However I want to get yaw, pitch and roll angles from these data. I tried to search for something like DMP which is used in the Arduino library but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTFBW-Mm4b0 you must integrate the velocity $\omega$ to get the angle position $\theta$. The velocity is obtained from the gyroscope.

Discrete integration can be made in few ways, one of them is
$$
\theta[i+1] = \theta[i] + \omega \cdot \, dt.
$$

So for yaw, pitch and roll angles you should calculate
$$
\theta_{yaw}[i+1] = \theta_y[i] + \omega_y[i] \cdot \, dt \\
\phi_{pitch}[i+1] = \theta_y[i] + \omega_x[i] \cdot \, dt \\
\rho_{roll}[i+1] = \theta_y[i] + \omega_z[i] \cdot \, dt 
$$